# How to post API with parameters for HTTPS with AFNetworking iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I am hitting API with parameters with AFNetworking on HTTPS URL on iOS 9. My request is not sending the correct parameters to the server. I have put the keys in a plist and that doesn't work with the API.

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, that if this is running on the simulator (Xcode 7/iOS9) you will probably need to add the `NSAppTransportSecurity > NSAllowsArbitraryLoads == YES key/value into your info.plist` for ANY communication to the outside world.  This is the first requirement (simply making sure that you *can* hit an endpoint).  Once that's done you'll need to use whatever API AFNetworking provides for your purposes.

Comment: I use API with alamofire (swift1.2) on xcode 6.4 .it works fine.but in xcode 7 it don't  work

Answer (score 0):

during Api Post i was sending dictionary as parameters which creates problem.Solution for Problem is given Below

```
paraDict =
{
email ="xyz@abc.co"
password = "1234567"
}

make string of parameters 

 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@"paraDict[@"email"],paraDict[@"password"]];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```